# In a hashtable, how can I get the object values by its key?

Tags: c#, hashtable

What I'm trying to do is get the values of an object in a given hashtable, thanks to its key.
Here is my code:

```
Hashtable quotidiani = new Hashtable();

Giornale corriere = new Giornale();
corriere.nome("Corriere della Sera");
corriere.direttore("Ferruccio de Bortoli");
corriere.anno("1876");
quotidiani.Add("corriere", corriere);

Giornale repubblica = new Giornale();
repubblica.nome("la Repubblica");
repubblica.direttore("Ezio Mauro");
repubblica.anno("1976");
quotidiani.Add("repubblica", repubblica);

Giornale ilFatto = new Giornale();
ilFatto.nome("Il Fatto Quotidiano");
ilFatto.direttore("Antonio Padellaro");
ilFatto.anno("2009");
quotidiani.Add("ilfatto", ilFatto);

/*IDictionaryEnumerator enumeratore = quotidiani.GetEnumerator();

Console.WriteLine("Di quale quotidiano vuoi visionare le informazioni? (scrivi la chiave): ");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
while (enumeratore.MoveNext()) { 

    if (quotidiani.ContainsKey(answer))
{
    Giornale grl = (Giornale)enumeratore.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Nome: {0}, Direttore: {1}, Anno di fondazione: {2}", grl.getNome(), grl.getDirettore(), grl.getAnno());
    Console.WriteLine("la chiave è presente");
    Console.WriteLine(quotidiani[answer]);
    break;
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Chiave non esistente");
    break;
}
```

```
class Giornale {
    string nomeQuotidiano = "";
    string dirQuotidiano = "";
    string annoQuotidiano = "";

    // Funzioni di assegnazione:
    public void nome(string nQuotidiano) {
        this.nomeQuotidiano = nQuotidiano;
    }

    public void direttore(string dQuotidiano) {
        this.dirQuotidiano = dQuotidiano;
    }

    public void anno(string aQuotidiano){
        this.annoQuotidiano = aQuotidiano;
    }

    // Funzioni di richiamo:
    public string getNome() {
        return this.nomeQuotidiano;
    }

    public string getDirettore() {
        return this.dirQuotidiano;
    }

    public string getAnno() {
        return this.annoQuotidiano;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if the name of the objects and stuff is in italian, I didn't think that I couldn't get stuck at this point.

Basically where I'm stuck is in the block of commented code: what I want to do is find in the hashtable one of its 3 object and get its elements using its key.

So, I want to put the key (with the readline method) and find the elements of the object associated to the key. How can I do that? Probably the solution is very simple, but I can't see it right now.

Comment: With [`Hashtable.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item(v=vs.110).aspx): i.e. `value = hashTable[key]`. But should probably use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) instead .. it's newer, is generic and conforms to generic IDictionary'/IEnumerable', and plays nicer with LINQ.

Comment: oft: You should use **[Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)** instead of custom, java-like `get`/`set` methods.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Hashtable quotidiani = new Hashtable();
 var value = quotidiani["key"];
```

More about hashtables can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Hashtables are kind of an old school type of collection in .NET, you might want to consider using [Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I will take a look at dictionaries, thanks. Now, the problem is that trying using the item property, what I get is the value associated to the key, not the value of the object(which is associated with the key). Basically, I get "Console.Application1.Giornale" instead of Nome, Direttore etc. Would you show me the exact process to use this property in this contest? Probably it's the right way to do what I want, but it's me that I'm dumb at doing this.

Answer (score -1):

I solved! The block of code that does what I meant is this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Di quale giornale vuoi le informazioni? (inserisci la chiave)");
        var key = Console.ReadLine();

        var value = quotidiani[key];

        Giornale grl = (Giornale)value;



        Console.WriteLine("Nome: {0}, Direttore: {1}, Anno di fondazione: {2}",grl.getNome(), grl.getDirettore(), grl.getAnno());
```

Thank you all for the tips :P